# Querying in Firebase with equalTo condition not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have database structure like this in Firebase

[image]

I want to search a search on this structure based on key **number** and get the parent key in return. Meaning if i search for **8860124421** then i should get **-KTEtSR7chN8te1WaW-W** in return .

I am doing it like this in android -

```
final String number = "8860124421";

DatabaseReference global_user_entry_ref = ApplicationContext.getGlobalDataBaseReference()
                .child("User-Entry-2").getRef();  //Reference to User-Entry-2 

Query query = global_user_entry_ref.orderByChild("number").equalTo(number);  

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot != null){

                        for(DataSnapshot friend: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            String firebase_id = (String) friend.getKey();

                            Log.d("ContactSync","handle number "+firebase_id+" "+number+" "+friend);
                        }

                        Log.d("ContactSync","handle number outer "+dataSnapshot);
                        //user exist
                    }
                    else {
                        //user_does_not_exist
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("ContactSync","handle number oncancel "+databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

But I am not getting proper result , **dataSanpshot** in **onDataChange** looks like this -

> DataSnapshot { key = User-Entry-2, value = null }

but i want to get dataSnapShot with parent of number key.

Please help , Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `number` variable that you pass in defined as a number? Or is it a string?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen...number is defined as string

Comment: Why does your question say "9758210790"?

Comment: That means you're comparing a number from your code with a string in the database, which doesn't match. Try `final long number = 8860124421;`

Comment: @cricket_007..sorry my mistake and thanks for pointing out

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you sir , it worked

Comment: I consider this a typo, so will vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

As @Frank van Puffelen stated in comments , the problem was that i was comparing a number from code with a string in the database , which does not match , Therefore the solution is to change

```
final String number = "8860124421";
```

to

```
final long number = 8860124421;
```